# Rails has_many of same model, but different instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm building a workout-tracking app. Currently, my models are set up so...
a user has_many schedules
a schedule has_many workouts
a workout has many exercises
an exercise has_many circuits (includes reps/sets/weights).

That all works fine.

But now I'm adding a new relationship I'm unsure how to setup.
I'd like to have a new model a user has_many "completed_workouts" which holds all of the attributes of the workout model.

My first idea was to add a user_workout model; with a foreign key for users and workouts. but that means whenever I make a change in the workout, it would also be reflected in user.workouts; which is not what I want.

## schema.rb

```
    create_table "circuits", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer "weight"
        t.integer "reps"
        t.integer "rest"
        t.integer "exercise_id"
      end
    
      create_table "exercises", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "name"
      end
    
      create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "name"
      end
    
      create_table "user_schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer "user_id"
        t.integer "schedule_id"
      end
    
    
      create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.string "username"
    
      end
    
      create_table "workout_exercises", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer "workout_id"
        t.integer "exercise_id"
      end
    
      create_table "workout_schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer "workout_id"
        t.integer "schedule_id"
      end
    
      create_table "workouts", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "name"
      end
```

## user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_schedules
  has_many :schedules, through: :user_schedules
end
```

## schedule.rb

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_schedules
  has_many :users, through: :user_schedules

  has_many :workout_schedules
  has_many :workouts,through: :workout_schedules

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workouts

end
```

## workout.rb

```
class Workout < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :workout_exercises
  has_many :exercises,through: :workout_exercises
  has_many :workout_schedules
  has_many :schedules,through: :workout_schedules

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for this that I can think of, both, requiring a certain degree of data redundancy.

**Solution 1: Add user_workout model which stores a point in time copy of the workout table**

In this approach, you could add the `user_workout` model as you had planned, but instead of keeping just a reference to the `workout`, you could copy the attributes that you require to the `user_workout` model. This would mean that when your `workout` values later change, your `user_workout` would continue to reflect the value of the workout that the user had undertaken.

Table structure:

1. user_id: integer
2. workout_id: integer (for reference)
3. All other columns of the workout

Advantages:

1. User workout values do not change, even if workout changes

Disadavntages:

1. Data duplication (Which in this case is required to an extent)
2. Whenever new columns are added to `workout`, they would need to be added to `user_workout` as well.

However, in case you're storing the values just for display purposes and are not going to perform any computation operations on them, you could simply have a hash field called `worker_snapshot` in `user_workout` instead of all the columns. That would overcome the second drawback.

**Solution 2: Make a new entry to the workouts table, whenever an edit is made to it**

This approach assumes that a workout can only have fixed values, and if anything changes in the workout, that means a new workout is being created. This would mean there are no such things as "updates" to workouts, but simply creation of new workouts with modified values of old ones, if an update is required. The `user_workout` table could then point to the `workout_id` directly without worrying about the workout data changing.

Advantages:

1. Does not require the `user_workout` table to worry about changes to `workouts`

Disadvantages:

1. Could bloat the workout table

Both these approaches may help in handling the scenario you have described. I'd personally prefer the first approach with the `workout_snapshot` hash.

**NOTE:** I'd recommend de-normalizing the database structure. A couple of your tables have only `name` columns, and linked to other tables as a many to many relation. Some things I'd recommend changing:

1. You could have a `name` field in `user_schedules` itself, and remove the `schedules` table. The `user_schedule` itself could have various exercises.
2. An exercise could have a name as well as a `workout_id`, and the `workout_exercises` table could be removed.

These are just recommendations which I thought may help in reducing the complexity of the DB structure. I understand that I have a very limited idea of what you're building and this recommendation could be pretty useless, in which case you can ignore it!

Comment: appreciate your suggestetions with the table changes. I think the first aproach makes more sense, for my use case. If i go with the first solution, would the user_workout model look identical to the workout model file? with the same associations?

Comment: Yes, it would if you don't use the snapshot hash. But, like I said, if it's just for the sake of displaying things or keeping track, I'd strongly recommend just using a single hash to keep the snapshot.

Comment: The drawback of maintaining associations on the `user_workout` model are that they may become a nightmare to maintain in case workouts or their relationships change. For example, what happens when the circuits associated with an exercise change? In that case, `user_workouts` would also start to point to the new circuit.
That's the reason I'd prefer Solution 1 + snapshot hash, or solution 2 instead as solution 1 without the hash may lead to maintainability issues.